# use QAudioOutput from QThread to play sound asynchronously

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am trying for a long time to play asynchronously a generated sound with `QAudioOutput`, from a `QThread`. To use `QAudioOutput` into `QThread`, we need `QThread` to have its own event loop. So, I start from [doc example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) by using `QObject::moveToThread()` method.

Sound is generated ok. Because if I play sound and wait to finish `sound->playSound(true);` then the sound is played ok. But if I use `sound->playSound(false);` then there is no sound, like there is no event loop.

I use `while(1){}` because in original code, `Interpreter` is a long `while()` loop in which many things happen (graphics, sounds, etc.).

1) If I wait the sound `sound->playSound(true);` I got this output:

```
try playSound
handleAudioStateChanged ActiveState
handleAudioStateChanged IdleState
return from playSound
```

2) If I play the sound asynchronously `sound->playSound(false);` I got this output:

```
try playSound
handleAudioStateChanged ActiveState
return from playSound
```

**How can I play asynchronously a sound with `QAudioOutput` from a `QThread` while doing a lot of other things expensive into an infinite loop?**

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

void Interpreter::doWork() {
    bool result = false;
    sound = new SoundSystem();
    qDebug() << "try playSound";
    sound->playSound(true); //bool wait=true/false
    qDebug() << "return from playSound";
    while(1){}
    emit resultReady(result);
}

Controller::Controller() {
    interpreterThread = new QThread();
    Interpreter *i = new Interpreter;
    connect(interpreterThread, &QThread::finished, i, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, &Controller::startInterpreter, i, &Interpreter::doWork);
    connect(i, &Interpreter::resultReady, this, &Controller::stopRunFinalized);
    i->moveToThread(interpreterThread);
    interpreterThread->start();
}

Controller::~Controller() {
    interpreterThread->quit();
    interpreterThread->wait();
}

void Controller::stopRunFinalized(bool i){
    qDebug() << "stopRunFinalized";
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent){
    Controller *t = new Controller;
    t->startInterpreter();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include "Sound.h"

class Interpreter : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    SoundSystem *sound;
public slots:
    void doWork();
signals:
    void resultReady(bool);
};


class Controller : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller();
    ~Controller();
    QThread *interpreterThread;
//public slots:
    void stopRunFinalized(bool);
signals:
    void startInterpreter();
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};
```

**Sound.cpp** - used to generate a simple wave sound for 2 seconds

```
#include "Sound.h"
#include <QDebug>

void  SoundSystem::playSound(bool wait) {
    double wave;
    double wavebit;
    short s;
    char *cs = (char *) &s;
    QByteArray* array = new QByteArray();
    QBuffer buffer(array);
    const double pi = 4*atan(1.0);

    buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Truncate);
    wave=0.0;
    wavebit=0.0;

    // lets build a sine wave into buffer
    int length = 44100 * 440 / 1000;
    wavebit = 2 * pi / (44100.0 / 1000.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        s = (int16_t) (0x7fff * sin(wave));
        buffer.write(cs,sizeof(int16_t));
        wave+=wavebit;
    }
    buffer.seek(0);

    // setup the audio format
    format.setSampleRate(44100);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);   // 16 bit audio
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    audio = new QAudioOutput(format);
    connect(audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleAudioStateChanged(QAudio::State)));
    audio->start(&buffer);

    if(wait){
        QEventLoop *loop = new QEventLoop();
        QObject::connect(audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), loop, SLOT(quit()));
        do {
            loop->exec(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
        } while(audio->state() == QAudio::ActiveState);
        delete (loop);
    }
}

void SoundSystem::handleAudioStateChanged(QAudio::State newState){
    qDebug() << "handleAudioStateChanged" << newState;
}
```

**Sound.h**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <QObject>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QEventLoop>

class SoundSystem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void playSound(bool wait);
    QAudioOutput* audio;
    QAudioFormat format;
private slots:
    void handleAudioStateChanged(QAudio::State);
};
```

Comment: if `wait == false`, then there is no event loop because it's not created (and it's useless anyways because it's in the `interpreterThread` that has already an event loop). Easiest solution would be to create `SoundSystem` in the main event loop (in the `Controller::Controller()` constructor) and send signals to it to start and stop playing. You can also make a separate thread for the sound, but it's tricky to do it correctly: even your current `interpreterThread` is flaky: can freeze if `interpreterThread->quit();` executes too soon after `interpreterThread->start();`.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation says that `interpreterThread` should have an event loop. But if I play sound with `wait == false` followed by `while(1){}` there is no sound. If I play it with `wait == true` then everything is OK. How can I play asynchronously a sound with QAudioOutput from a QThread?